# Chrome adds unwanted margins to xaringan rmarkdown output

Tags: javascript, r, google-chrome, r-markdown, xaringan

I am trying to print a PDF of a xaringan markdown that I have created. When I open up the html created by the R markdown, it renders perfectly fine in my browser. However, when I go to print it as a PDF (using the "Save as PDF" option), it adds large white margins to the bottom and right sides of the slides.

I can avoid this by using pagedown but my workplace only allows me to use chrome to convert to PDF. To double check, I ran the hello world example from https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/xaringan-start.html, opened it in chrome, tried to print it and got the same results.

I did this on two separate computers to double check that it wasnt just my machine.

I am running 3.5.2 for R and 0.13 of Xaringan (from CRAN).

PS: It looks like this used to be a problem with Xaringan https://github.com/yihui/xaringan/issues/65

EDIT:
Adding the code from https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/xaringan-start.html

```
---
title: "Presentation Ninja"
subtitle: "with xaringan"
author: "Yihui Xie"
date: "2016/12/12"
output:
  xaringan::moon_reader:
    lib_dir: libs
    nature:
      highlightStyle: github
      countIncrementalSlides: false
---

One slide.

---

Another slide.
```

Comment: What version of `xaringan` are you using?

Comment: Give `xaringan::decktape()` a try.

Comment: More more detailed help, you need to provide a reproducible example.

Comment: Hi Pat, for the reproducible example, I am using the hello world example from the provided link. I will update my question with the code itself. Thanks!

Comment: @ekstroem I am using 0.13 from CRAN. I only have access to CRAN at my place of work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the dev version fixes your issue but if you only have access to the CRAN version, add the following to a css file, say `custom.css`,

```
@page { margin: 0; }
@media print {
  .remark-slide-scaler {
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 100% !important;
    transform: scale(1) !important;
    top: 0 !important;
    left: 0 !important;
  }
}
```

then refer to this css file in the YAML of the Rmd like below

```
output:
  xaringan::moon_reader:
    css: "custom.css"
```